# Redirect page URL to home URL without using a plugin

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect

How do I redirect this page URL, `http://localhost/wordpress_rnd/?page_id=2`, to the home URL, `http://localhost/wordpress_rnd/`, without using any plugins?

Answer (score 20):

The correct way to do this is using the [`template_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) hook by adding a function to your `functions.php`:

```
function redirect_to_home() {
  if(!is_admin() && is_page('2')) {
    wp_redirect(home_url());
    exit();
  }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_to_home');
```

Comment: could you tell me why do we have to use exit after     wp_redirect(home_url()); ?

Comment: Good question and I can't say for sure, but I know that [the official documentation example uses it](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/), so I use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    if ( 0 === stripos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/page_id=2' ) ) {

       wp_redirect( home_url(), 301 );
       exit;

    }
}
```

Put this code in a mu-plugin or in your theme's functions.php file

Answer (score -1):

Locate page.php (assuming you've created it already). After this line `<?php get_header(); ?>` add the following code:

```
<?php if(is_page('2')) {
    wp_redirect( home_url(), '302' ); 
} ?>
```

In the code above, `is_page('2')` is actually the ID of your page as  you've specified in your example.

Comment: This can do the job but I think it is better, depending on the exact situation, to do the redirection at server level, for example using .htaccess, so zero line of code is exectued and you don't waste resources.

Comment: @cybmeta valid point indeed :) Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: One more note. Use your code in an action hook, like `init` suggested by @paul in his answer, not in a template file as you suggested. If you switch to other theme, you loose the funtionality, that is why functinalities and look&feel (theme and template file) should be separated. I would edit the answer to add the action hook.

Comment: True as well. There's time one doesn't think about optimising the code but the focus is on getting the task at hand done faster :) This is was (in my opinion) one of those scenarios. 

I do, however, really appreciate your input and it's really valuable - everyday I learn something new in here :)

Comment: Write your code in an action hook is as fast as write it in  a template file.

Comment: I was talking about the solutions as well. Sometimes, you just need to think fast and solve a quick job, sometimes you have to optimize a piece of code. Nonetheless, no code is bad, at least from my point of view.

Answer (score -1):

[WP_REDIRECT](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) is the function that you need to use for redirecting in wordpress. It can be used like :

```
wp_redirect( $location, $status );
exit;
//$location is required parameter. It is used to give the target url to which page will get redirected.
//$status is optional. It is used to set status code. Default is 302
```

You can use this function to redirect users from one page to other. It should be placed in either functions.php or the template file which is being used to display the current page. Now to use it in your situation, simple place the following code at the bottom of your functions.php file

```
$redirectFromPageID = 2;  //Redirect from Page having ID of 2
$redirectTo = home_url(); //Redirect to Home URL

if( is_page( $redirectFromPageID ) ){
    wp_redirect( $redirectTo  );
    exit;
}
```